# part of page cuting in android devices only

Tags: android, css, wordpress, google-chrome

I have a strange bug ...
WordPress site looks excellent in Chrome browser on a desktop when I'm at a resolution of a mobile device - attached screenshot.

[image]
<sub>(source: [studio-hitchadshut.co.il](http://studio-hitchadshut.co.il/ps1.jpg))</sub>

When I on chrome in real Android device S3 - Homepage cut off after the middle of the page ... 
Another screenshot attached.

[image]
<sub>(source: [studio-hitchadshut.co.il](http://studio-hitchadshut.co.il/ps2.jpg))</sub>

the temp url of site is here:

```
http://174.137.187.89/~honenuor/
```

This only happens on Android device and not on desktop ... 
Anyone can help?

Comment: Is this a programming question?

Comment: won't be that black part not your video not rescaled ?

Comment: i dont think is the video - its look like the page just cut off...

Comment: i can remove the video But the problem remains

Comment: The problem was due to a JavaScript error related to royalslider.
Very strange that only Android device this problem making it part of the page is cut off while an ordinary computer or Apple devices there is no problem.
This is why I think this problem Andoraid - or maybe that's just the problem of processor / memory?